# A bound function for an event Listener

Tags: javascript, binding, addeventlistener

I wanted to understand how do bound functions used for an event listener work. I get that the first parameter for `.bind()` is a new context, thus the .this keyword being altered, but why can't I pass more arguments along with that?
It isn't much of a problem, since the event object is passed through simply by having a parameter in the function, but why is it implied? That's the part I don't understand too

```
const nav = document.querySelector(`.nav`);

const handleOver = function (e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains(`nav__link`)) {
    const link = e.target;
    const siblings = link.closest(`.nav`).querySelectorAll(`.nav__link`);
    const logo = link.closest(`.nav`).querySelector(`img`);

    siblings.forEach(el => {
      if (el !== link) {
        el.style.opacity = this;
      }
    });
    logo.style.opacity = this;
  }
};

nav.addEventListener(`mouseover`, handleOver.bind(0.5));

nav.addEventListener(`mouseout`, handleOver.bind(1));
```

Tried passing more arguments (with given parameters of course) but it just doesn't work as I expected

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can pass more arguments to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). The first argument sets the `this` value and any subsequent arguments fix the values of the arguments passed to the function before any additional arguments that are passed when the function is invoked.

You just need to allow the event handler function to accept enough parameters. The event object will be passed as an argument to the handler, which would make it the last argument of the bound function.

Example:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(arg1, event) {
  console.log(this, arg1, event.target);
}.bind({test: 1}, "arg 1"));
```

```html
Click here
```

Comment: Thanks! I run the code on VS code and figured it out with your explanation